# Access EMR Task logs from Hadoop Job Tracker web interface

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, emr

I've opened the EC2 security groups for my master/slave nodes so I can access the job tracker interface from my local browser. I connect to it using `http://MASTER-IP:9100`.

Everything works well until I try to access the task tracker logs from the task details - `http://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9100/taskdetails.jsp?tipid=task_201212181113_0001_m_000000`

The links I get there are to the internal EC2 IP addresses, therefore I cannot access them from my local machine (links are `http://10.116.xxx.xx:9103/tasklog?attemptid=attempt_201212181113_0001_m_000000_0&all=true` )

Is there a way to change EMR so that those links will contain the task tracker's public IP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you can do very easily is `ssh` to the master node and from there you cab to a `curl` to this log location. Generally we always tunnel to the master node and access the Job tracker web iterface via `http://localhost:9100`

In order to tunnel you can do the following:

```
ssh -i your-pem-file.pem -L 9100:ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.computamazonaws.com:9100 hadoop@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

And then access the logs via simple `curl`, something like :

```
$ curl http://10.116.xxx.xx:9103/tasklog?attemptid=attempt_201212181113_0001_m_000000_0&all=true
```

You can also login to your aws console and there look for the list of running ec2 instances. From there you can get the private IP and corresponding public IP for the machine's log you want, you can then replace the private IP with this retrieved public IP in the log's URL and you are good to go.

But first solution is pretty simple and is what we do generally.

Answer (score 2):

Add the public IPs of all the slaves along with their Hostnames into your /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh tunneling. And use Firefox-Plugin FoxyProxy. you should be able to see the job tracker interface from the local browser and browse the logs